# How do I pass options to forcefsck?

Tags: linux, filesystems, disk, fsck

I am trying to run a one time disk check at bootup by using /forcefsck but I would like to pass some of the FSCK options such as y, c, f, and v. I have tried inserting these in the file but I seems to ignore them. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

The method you are using by creating a `/forcefsck` file in the root directory of each filesystem you want to force a check on, only works in a pure `SysVinit` environment, or an older `Upstart` init environment. It doesn't work on a system using `systemd` init. I also am assuming you are on an `ext4` filesystem.

The way to run a one time filesystem check at boot with `systemd`, is to pass one or both of these kernel command parameters at boot time.

> `fsck.mode=[auto|force|skip]`
>
> and/or:
>
> `fsck.repair=[preen|yes|no]`

If you're using `GRUB` as the boot loader, press `e` at the menu to add kernel boot parameters as the last entries of the field that starts something like: `linux  /vmlinuz-x.x.x-x-amd64....`

You also could add these kernel parameters to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=` field of `/etc/default/grub` by editing that file with root privilege, and follow up with an `# update-grub` and reboot to test, but that would make the checks permanent at each boot until you remove them.

Check your `man systemd-fsck` for an explanation of these options.

Comment: Thanks. I'm testing on Ubuntu 14.04 which my understanding is that it uses both System V and Upstart as I see some services controlled by both. I do however see a "systemd-udevd --dameon" running when I do a ps check and I see a "systemd-logind" service controlled by upstart. It is an ext4 FS I am checking. I don't have a man entry for systemd-fsck. Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: I was able to edit the grub boot params but no luck. I tried adding both of your entries, both as single entries and both together. After I hit F10 to continue booting it gave me "error: syntax error" and "error: incorrect command" so not sure if the its a problem with your examples or maybe I'm putting it in the wrong place. There was only one "Linux   /boot/vmlinux....." line and I placed it at the end of that line, with a space between it and the last character.

Comment: Embrassed to say but the above answer probably does not apply to you since you are on Ubuntu 14.04, I should have asked you first.  This does apply to pure `systemd` installations. Not to send you on a wild goose chase but try this. Look for a file `/etc/default/rcS`,  and with root privilege, change the line `FSCKFIX` to `yes`, and save,  then reboot. This means "automatically repair filesystems with inconsistencies during boot" and causes `fsck` to run with the `-y` flag.

Comment: Yes, that method does work however it will only check if problems are found. Hard to believe that manually forcing before/during reboot with options is not possible with Ubuntu :( Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm sorry I've not worked on Ubuntu extensively, mainly just Debian. It does seem strange that this procedure is difficult. The `/forcefsck` option is a legacy `SysVinit` method, it doesnt work with `systemd`  but the above procedure works fine on systems based in it, I've used it many times. I think there must be an Ubuntu 14.04 specific method cause the `/forcefsck` method works in older Ubuntu releases.

Answer (score -1):

Excellent Stuff:  This might be as good same way of saying the same thing. In *nix there are many ways to skin a cat. Maybe as simple

```
cd /etc/default
sudo cp rcS rcS.org
sudo vi rcS
```

Then use <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> to jump to the end of the file.

`x` the `#` in front of `FSCKFIX=no`
change `=no` to `=yes`
then save write file

reboot test

This is resourced from `/etc/rcS.d/S11checkfs.sh`  primary script. viewing should show it to be pretty covered for checking your file system on boot-ups.