# unable to rm/chmod even with sudo

Tags: filesystems, ls

I'm still kind of new to linux, but was already able to solve most of the issues with resources on the web. However there is an issues which I need help with:

when <kbd>ls -al</kbd> in terminal, there seems to be an error:

```
total 400
drwxr-xr-x 1 allen allen  2496 Nov 12 19:31 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 allen allen   792 Nov 12 19:18 ..
.
.
.
drwxr-xr-x 1 allen allen    22 Nov  7 12:52 OpenLP
-rw------- 1 allen allen    27 Nov  2 17:17 plasma-localerc
-rw------- 1 allen allen    36 Nov  2 17:17 plasma-nm
-rw------- 1 allen allen  1022 Nov 12 19:31 plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
-rw------- 1 allen allen  1022 Nov 12 19:31 plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
-rw------- 1 allen allen  1022 Nov 12 19:31 plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
-rw------- 1 allen allen  1022 Nov 12 19:31 plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
-rw------- 1 allen allen  1022 Nov 12 19:31 plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
-rw------- 1 allen allen  1022 Nov 12 19:31 plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
-rw------- 1 allen allen  1022 Nov 12 19:31 plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
-rw------- 1 allen allen  1022 Nov 12 19:31 plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
-rw------- 1 allen allen  1022 Nov 12 19:31 plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
-rw------- 1 allen allen  1022 Nov 12 19:31 plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
-rw------- 1 allen allen  1022 Nov 12 19:31 plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
-rw------- 1 allen allen  1022 Nov 12 19:31 plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
-rw------- 1 allen allen  1022 Nov 12 19:31 plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
-rw------- 1 allen allen  1022 Nov 12 19:31 plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
-rw------- 1 allen allen  1022 Nov 12 19:31 plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
-rw------- 1 allen allen  1022 Nov 12 19:31 plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
-rw------- 1 allen allen  1022 Nov 12 19:31 plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
-????????? ? ?     ?         ?            ? plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc.lock
-????????? ? ?     ?         ?            ? plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc.lock
-????????? ? ?     ?         ?            ? plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc.lock
-????????? ? ?     ?         ?            ? plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc.lock
-????????? ? ?     ?         ?            ? plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc.lock
-????????? ? ?     ?         ?            ? plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc.lock
-????????? ? ?     ?         ?            ? plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc.lock
-????????? ? ?     ?         ?            ? plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc.lock
-????????? ? ?     ?         ?            ? plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc.lock
-????????? ? ?     ?         ?            ? plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc.lock
-????????? ? ?     ?         ?            ? plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc.lock
-????????? ? ?     ?         ?            ? plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc.lock
-????????? ? ?     ?         ?            ? plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc.lock
-????????? ? ?     ?         ?            ? plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc.lock
-????????? ? ?     ?         ?            ? plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc.lock
-????????? ? ?     ?         ?            ? plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc.lock
-????????? ? ?     ?         ?            ? plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc.lock
-rw-r--r-- 1 allen allen    73 Nov  4 13:31 plasmarc
-rw------- 1 allen allen  1139 Nov 12 18:57 plasmashellrc
drwxr-xr-x 1 allen allen    22 Nov  2 17:17 plasma-workspace
-rw------- 1 allen allen    44 Nov  2 17:17 powerdevilrc
-rw------- 1 allen allen   890 Nov  4 13:39 powermanagementprofilesrc
drwx------ 1 allen allen     0 Nov  6 22:10 procps
drwxr-xr-x 1 allen allen    30 Nov 12 18:58 Projecteur
drwx------ 1 allen allen   500 Nov  2 17:17 pulse
drwxr-xr-x 1 allen allen   112 Oct 20 09:19 qpdfview
drwxr-xr-x 1 allen allen    24 Nov  4 14:33 Qt
drwx------ 1 allen allen     0 Nov  4 13:32 qtcurve
drwxr-xr-x 1 allen allen    68 Nov  4 15:52 QtProject
```

However a simple <kbd>ls</kbd> will list files and directories without errors.

I tried to use <kbd>sudo rm -rf</kbd> but it replied cannot access file, and <kbd>sudo chmod</kbd> gave the same result. What can I do?

this account does have sudo privilege:

```
sudo cat /etc/sudoers                                              1 (0.002s)
[sudo] password for allen: 
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
# Host alias specification
# User alias specification
# Cmnd alias specification
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
allen    ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/onedrive-stop.sh
allen    ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/onedrive-start.sh
# See sudoers(5) for more information on "@include" directives:
@includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Comment: There may be filesystem corruption.  What is the underlying device?

Comment: If possible, unmount the filesystem ans run an `fsck` on it.  If not possible, make sure that an `fsck` runs at the next boot (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/222926/237080).

Comment: it's the ~/.config/ directory on a sata SSD. I will try fsck at the next boot. Thanks

Comment: Tried changing to root user or changing files ownership?

Answer (score 0):

Because the installation is on a btrfs partition which contains both the root and the home directories, I booted from a live USB, and used the following command to fix the problem

<kbd>sudo btrfs check --repair /dev/sda3</kbd>

change the device path accordingly if you want to apply this

Thank you all for your input